# What does environment set up do

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*(This is a basic quest. I'm new to ROS.)*

I know that environment set up is setting up the environment, but **what environment? What is actually set up there? Any example?...(1)**

From this [ros tutorial page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch):

> If roscd says similar to roscd: No
> such package/stack
> 'beginner_tutorials' , you will need
> to source the environment setup file
> like you did at the end of the
> create_a_workspace tutorial:
>
> $ cd ~/catkin_ws $ source
> devel/setup.bash $ roscd
> beginner_tutorials

**Why do I have to setup again  if previously I have set it up?...(2)**

Before setup , *roscd beginner_tutorials* can't be executed, but after set up, it can. **What does set up actually do here?...(3)**

Lastly, when installing ROS according to this [Ros installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#indigo.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup)
,we set up the environment for ros.
My quests are:
**Again, what environment is set up/what is actually being set up here?...(4)**

***Why for this one we don't need to set up the ros env everytime open a new session, unlike the previous one where we have to set up again eventhough we once set it up?...(5)***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241528/what-does-environment-set-up-do/) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The primary thing that happens when you source your catkin workspace's `devel/setup.bash` file is that you are setting **environment variables**.

For example, you'll notice a difference in many environment variables before & after sourcing the setup file:

- ROS_PACKAGE_PATH: This tells ROS where to find packages, so that `rosrun <pkg> <node>` actually works.
- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: This tells the compiler a bunch of stuff, including where to find the libraries defined in your package.
- LD_LIBRARY_PATH: This is used at execution time to dynamically load shared libraries.
- PYTHONPATH: This tells python where to look for any python modules defined in your package.

(There are others, there are just the important ones).

As an example, this is my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH before and after sourcing the setup file in some random catkin workspace:

```
$ cd /path/to/my/catkin_ws
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH 
/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
$ source devel/setup.bash
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/path/to/my/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Note the addition of my catkin workspace's `src/` directory to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. This enables me to run any nodes I have defined in my workspace, otherwise only the system-installed packages are available. (Side note: `/opt/ros/<distro>/` basically acts as one big catkin workspace too.)

Normally, you always source the *global* `/opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash` every time you open a terminal because it's in your `.bashrc` file. However, since new terminal sessions don't carry over environment variables, you need to source **your** workspace's setup file again each time you open a new session.

If you do not want to have to source the workspace setup file yourself each time you open a new terminal, you can always add it to your `.bashrc` file:

```
echo "source /path/to/your/workspace/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Obviously this only works if you have a single catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) with karma: 539 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-08-11**:
Very helpful answer! Technically the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not for any compiler, it's for used by `ld.so` at execution time to dynamically load shared libraries. Without it, you could have a piece of code that compiles but doesn't run.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-08-11**:
That situation would depend on things like [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld) and `/etc/ld.so.cache`, and the `-rpath` flag of gcc/g++ (see [this tutorial, step 4](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)). The CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is like what you described.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-08-11**:
It is important for catkin/CMake to be able to find ROS libraries, and it is controlled by the setup.bash scripts.

**Comment by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on 2016-08-11**:
Thanks for the comment, you're absolutely right. I've updated the answer. I think the link to the shared libraries tutorial is still helpful as a comment.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-14**:
So everytime a new terminal is opened, it automatically source what's in bashrc file. And /opt/ros//setup.bash is in bashrc file, that's why I don't have to source it everytime i open terminal. While source devel/setup.bash is not, and that's why I have to source evertytime i open new term.